# Fetch all entities from case class and convert them to string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a case class like below:

```scala
case class Class1(field1: String,
                  field2: Option[String] = None,
                  var var1: Option[String] = None,
                  var var2: Option[Boolean] = None,
                  var var3: Option[Double] = None
)
```

The list of variables is a bit longer. Now I want to convert all variables, which are inside the class, into a string. Say `Option[]` must be omitted and also `Boolean`, `Double` and `Number` must be converted to string type. My first approach was:

```
def anyOptionalToString(class1Dataset: Dataset[Class1]): DataFrame = {
    val ds1 = class1Dataset.map { class1 =>
        (
          class1.field1,
          class1.field2.getOrElse(""),
          class1.var1.getOrElse(""),
          class1.var2.getOrElse(false),
          class1.var3.getOrElse(-1.0)
        )
 }
```

Is there a way to cast them without calling every field?
Speak in a kind of `loop` or something similar?

Comment: Look into pattern matching? You might also be able to simply do toString on the case class. It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do. Perhaps best for you to add more code

Comment: And the results for these conversions?. If you need to collect values of heterogeneous types into a new type you will need something like a HList https://www.scala-exercises.org/shapeless/heterogenous_lists  It is an advanced topic.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your quick response and sorry for my bad description. Mainly I want to encapsulate the case class and create a new construct with the same fields just casted as string. I have changed my description above and hope that I could express myself a bit clearer.

Comment: And the new construct is another specifict type?, a new case class, for example?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is creating a new `Seq` containing the defaults you want to have. Let's say:

```
val defaults = Seq("", "", "", false, -1)
```

Now, we can use the [`productIterator`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Product.html#productIterator:Iterator%5BAny%5D) to iterate over the existing elements, and choose whether we want to use the existing value, or the default:

```
val c1 = Class1("f1", Some("f2"), None, Some(true), Some(3))
c1.productIterator.zip(defaults.iterator).map {
  case (None, default) => default
  case (Some(value), _) => value
  case (value, _) => value
}.map(_.toString)
```

The resulting type of the code above is `Iterator[String]`. Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CxHlwd45RZmfmjJpnoexTA).